# PHP - Is it possible to get value from variable that is written under?

Tags: php

Sorry, it may be a very crazy question. I am trying to declare a variable without value first and I print its value next to it. However, its value will be set after printing.

```
$pre_var = '';
echo $pre_var ;
$pre_var  = 'This is my real value''
```

So "This is my real value" will be printed out.

Sorry for my bad English

**Edit:** I want to send value to title tag when php code that I write in body changes its value

Comment: Short answer. No.

Comment: This sounds like you are asking the wrong question. What is the _actual_ problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Why can't you declare the value first?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.
The php code will be interpreted at that moment with an empty value.

Its a very strange question you ask here, what are you trying to achieve ?
You might to explain a little bit more since this make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

No. PHP Scripts are read/executed from top to bottom. Therefore when you declare a variable with the same name twice, the second value will overwrite the first value:

```
$var = "My var";
echo $var; // "My var";

$var = "New var";
echo $var; // "New var";
```

The word "variable" means the data can change as PHP allows you to alter the value as you wish. But the bottom / lowest declaration of the variable will be the final result.

You could always re-assign the value to a new variable?

```
$new_var = $var;
```

Comment: This is not totaly correct. Offcours you can change the data, but the variable word means that the type is variable and can change during the way you program. With other words, PHP is a loosy typed language.

Answer (score 0):

this is not directly possible, however you could add a placeholder

```
echo '<!--SOME RANDOM PLACEHOLDER-->';
$var="the real text";
echo(str_repace("<!--SOME RANDOM PLACEHOLDER-->",$var,ob_get_clean()));
```

It takes the output buffer and overwrites your placeholder with the variable
It makes the placeholder `echo '<!--SOME RANDOM PLACEHOLDER-->';`
Then the variable is set `$var="the real text";`
Then the placeholder is replaced by the variable
`echo(str_repace("<!--SOME RANDOM PLACEHOLDER-->",$var,ob_get_clean()));`

Answer (score 0):

No, Simply it's not possible.

PHP scripts are interpreted from the top to the bottom. So by the time you echo the variable, it will not possess any value in it. So a blank value will be printed.

I'm wondering what blocks you from changing the order of your lines. Apparently, there is no restriction for you to assign the variable before you echo it (as the code snippet you posted.)

Like this,

```
$pre_var = ''; //this is even not needed now.
$pre_var  = 'This is my real value'; //here also you had a wrong syntax,
echo $pre_var;
```

Please post the actual piece of code you are working on, so we can have a good idea of what you want to do. :-)